# How to properly pause ingestion in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I have an Azure Event Hub connection populating a table in Azure Data Explorer. What if the table name or the data stream schema changes? Is it possible to pause the ingestion process (batch or streaming) to handle the changes and then resume it?

Until now, the only way I've found to pause the stream was to delete and then recreate the connection. The drawback is that it doesn't resume where it was (even with the same consumer group).

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.